# how to concat two object arrays of different size by key using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
Stocks: [{
    PRN: 1,
    PID: 1,
    Qty: 3,
    SlNos: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
    PRN: 1,
    PID: 2,
    Qty: 4,
    SlNos: [10, 11, 12, 13]
}, {
    PRN: 2,
    PID: 1,
    Qty: 3,
    SlNos: [4, 5, 6]
}, {
    PRN: 2,
    PID: 2,
    Qty: 4,
    SlNos: [14, 15, 16, 17]
}]
```

I want this array as bellow with Lodash

```
Stocks: [{
    PID: 1,
    Qty: 6,
    SlNos: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}, {
    PID: 2,
    Qty: 4,
    SlNos: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
}]
```

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far on your own?

Comment: https://codepen.io/cmtliton/pen/zmqXBO?editors=1011

Comment: Shows us what you got/tried please :)

Comment: "dummy": [
    {
      "PID": "1",
      "Qty": 6,
      "SlNos": []
    },
    {
      "PID": "2",
      "Qty": 8,
      "SlNos": []
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with _lodash:

```js
var stocks = [{ PRN: 1, PID: 1, Qty: 3, SlNos: [1, 2, 3] }, { PRN: 1, PID: 2, Qty: 4, SlNos: [10, 11, 12, 13] }, { PRN: 2, PID: 1, Qty: 3, SlNos: [4, 5, 6] }, { PRN: 2, PID: 2, Qty: 4, SlNos: [14, 15, 16, 17] }]

const result = _.reduce(stocks, (r, {PRN, ...c}) => {
   let _c = _.find(r, {'PID': c.PID})
   if(_c)
     _c = _.mergeWith(_c, c, (ov, sv, k) => _.includes(['Qty','SlNos'], k) ? _.isArray(sv) ? (ov || []).concat(sv) : _.isNumber(sv) ? sv + (ov || 0) : sv : ov)
   else
     r.push(c)
   return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

We are using [**reduce**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce) with [**mergeWith**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) (which is the main thing here really) plus a little bit of [includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#includes).

Here is a solution without lodash that will do the trick:

```js
var stocks = [{ PRN: 1, PID: 1, Qty: 3, SlNos: [1, 2, 3] }, { PRN: 1, PID: 2, Qty: 4, SlNos: [10, 11, 12, 13] }, { PRN: 2, PID: 1, Qty: 3, SlNos: [4, 5, 6] }, { PRN: 2, PID: 2, Qty: 4, SlNos: [14, 15, 16, 17] }]

const result = stocks.reduce((r, c) => {
  _c = r.find(x => x.PID === c.PID)
  if (_c) {
    _c.PID = c.PID
    _c.Qty = _c.Qty + c.Qty
    _c.SlNos = _c.SlNos ? _c.SlNos.concat(c.SlNos) : c.SlNos
  } else {
    r.push(!delete(c.PRN) || c)
  }
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to use `reduce` and first `find` if we had already that object by PID if so sum the values if not insert to the final array. Since we are going through each record that logic does the trick in one loop.

Comment: Problem Solve! Many Many Thanks. Great Solutions

Comment: Glad it helped. You should check this as the answer if it helped you so other can find it easier etc.

Comment: Anyone can solve it by Lodash or more easier. Please

Comment: Added lodash solution.

Comment: @Md.LitonMiah did the lodash solution help?

Comment: i am using your lodash solution. Thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: Awesome. It my answer helped you please mark it with the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: Got the result [
  {
    "PID": 1,
    "Qty": 6,
    "SlNos": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  },
  {
    "PID": 2,
    "Qty": 8,
    "SlNos": [
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16,
      17
    ]
  }
] Now How can i search by SlNo 2 and return it {PID: 1, SLNo: 2 }